# Matplotlib - Set background colour of specific quadrants

Tags: python, matplotlib

In `Jfreechart` there is a method called `setQuadrantPaint` which let's you set the background colour of a given quandrant in a plot.

How would you achieve the equivalent in `matplotlib`?

E.g.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can plot a 2x2 array with imshow in the background. Giving it an extent will make the center of it always at 0,0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1, y1 = np.random.randint(-8,8,5), np.random.randint(-8,8,5)
x2, y2 = np.random.randint(-8,8,5), np.random.randint(-8,8,5)

vmax = np.abs(np.concatenate([x1,x2,y1,y2])).max() + 5

extent = [vmax*-1,vmax, vmax*-1,vmax]
arr = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.scatter(x1,y1, marker='s', s=30, c='r', edgecolors='red', lw=1)
ax.scatter(x2,y2, marker='s', s=30, c='none', edgecolors='red', lw=1)

ax.autoscale(False)
ax.imshow(arr, extent=extent, cmap=plt.cm.Greys, interpolation='none', alpha=.1)

ax.axhline(0, color='grey')
ax.grid(True)
```

[image]

Setting the autoscale to False after the data points are plotted, but before the image is, makes sure that the axes scales only to the data points.